# Is there a way to iterate and reflect the member names and values contained in enumerations?

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, iteration, enumeration

Let's say I have the following `enum`:

```
public enum Colors
{
    White = 10,
    Black = 20,
    Red = 30,
    Blue = 40
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to iterate through all the members of `Colors` to find the member names and their values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) and [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors));
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors));

for (int i=0;i<names.Length;++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", names[i], (int)values.GetValue(i));
}
```

*Note: When I tried to run the code using `values[i]`, it threw an exception because `values` is of type `Array`.*

Comment: Wow, talk about similar examples. +1.

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah - not too different ;)

Comment: Great answer, but I'm curious: why `++i`?

Comment: @Ben: Instead of i++?  It's a habit from my C/C++ days where it mattered... (and where I still write a fair amount of code, so I like to keep the habit)

Comment: @Reed ahh, thanks for the explanation. Yes, I was curious in reference to `i++`. While I knew it was allowed in C#, I had never seen anyone use it and wasn't sure if there was a difference.

Comment: @Ben: See http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12634  When you use postfix operators, you typically force a constructor call.  In some compilers, they're actually even slower on primitives (most modern ones optimize it out, though).

Comment: @Ben: I don't like to micro-optimize, but I also try to just build habits that prevent having to optimize later :)  This is one I've picked up over the years.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < typeof(DepartmentEnum).GetFields().Length - 1; i++)
            {
                DepartmentEnum de = EnumExtensions.NumberToEnum<DepartmentEnum>(i);
                pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(de.ToDescription(), de.ToString()));
            }
```

Here is the extension itself:

```
  public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string ToDescription(this Enum en) 
        {
            Type type = en.GetType();

            MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

            if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),false);

                if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)

                    return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
            }

            return en.ToString();
        }

        public static TEnum NumberToEnum<TEnum>(int number )
        {
            return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), number);
        }
    }
```